# how to get one value in option tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript

If i am having 2 values in a  tag, can I get first value(postcode) alone using `e.options[e.selectedIndex].value`

My option tag is,

```
<option value="<?php echo $address['postcode'];?> , <?php echo $address['address_id']; ?>" selected="selected"> Address </option>
```

If it's not possible, how can I get it?

Comment: You only have one value, consisting of a string with a comma  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can split address string by `,`. The resulting array would contain two elements: post code (the first) and what you called address id as the second.

```
var address = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value.split(','),
    postCode = address[0],
    addressId = address[1];
```

Comment: Good, feel free to accept the answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [**split()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
var address = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value.split(',');
first = address[0];
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rkwa746j/)